# AuthException not resolved to a type and multiple dex files - Build path

Tags: android, eclipse, api, build, path

I have downloaded a google android sample project which can be found at: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html

I have added the google calendar api and registered the project etc.
I first had nine errors:

1. GoogleAuthException cannot be resolved to a type
2. GoogleAuthException cannot be resolved to a type
3. GoogleAuthException cannot be resolved to a type
4. GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved
5. GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved
6. GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved
7. Incompatible conditional operand types throwable and GoogleAuthException
8. The import com.android.google.gms cannot be resolved
9. The import com.android.google.gms cannot be resolved

I looked up the internet to fix the first error and then I added google-play-services.jar to the buld path which is located in programs/development/SDK/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs

This got rid of all none errors. When I try to run the program I get the message in the console:

```
[2013-04-09 18:58:46 - AndroidCalendar] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file    C:\Users\Calendar\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-04-09 18:58:48 - AndroidCalendar] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Calendar\bin\jarlist.cache
[2013-04-09 19:00:39 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
[2013-04-09 19:00:39 - calendar-android-sample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
[2013-04-09 21:17:13 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
[2013-04-09 21:17:13 - calendar-android-sample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
[2013-04-09 21:30:49 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
[2013-04-09 21:30:49 - calendar-android-sample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
```

I also get this error in the problems tab:
    conversion to Dalvik format failed: unable to execute dex: multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils

What I have tried:
1.Clean project and rebuild 2.restart eclipse

- added the following jar files to the class path (with no change to
  multiple dex files error):
- google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar gson-2.1.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar jsr305-1.3.9.jar protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar

The only other recommended jar file to include is guava-11.0.1.jar as I cannot find it in any files. The 6 jar files above are in the path: users/android./googleapi/libs

Did I fix the first nine errors wrong by including the google-play-services.jar file or is there just another problem with my buildpath now?

**edit**
In the file --> referenced libraries/bin/dexed libs on eclipse I can see that there are some jar files repeated. I deleted the repeated ones and cleaned the project to run again and the error still presists and i noticed the files i deleted in that folder have returned.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the google project added to my class path, as well as a local reference. I had to manually edit the `.classpath` file (assuming you are using eclipse) to do it. Then I had to restart eclispe, and clean/rebuild a few times.

Also I found an article which suggested you should copy the google play services library into your workspace and reference it from there, that seemed to help my project a lot.

Comment: I have google_play_service.jar added to my class path. How do you add the google play services library? I think this is my problem now. @yano Thanks

Comment: Copy "google-play-services_lib" folder from `%sdk%/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject` to a workspace folder. Import existing Android project from eclipse. I had to re-mark the "Is Library" check box for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In Build path , you have selected both Tasks Api + private dependencies , uncheck private dependencies and run

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project. Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Under the Order and export tab, make sure only the jar file is selected, or just one box is selected.